# Is there any way for incremental data loading in cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have Cassandra v 1.0.12 cluster running.
I want to migrate data to new cluster of same cassandra version.
Data load using sstableloader takes time (approx 1 day) and I cannot have any downtime on existing cluster.
Also currently incremental backups are not turned on live site.

If I copy sstables and load them using sstableloader, How can I move delta into new cluster (new data which got inserted in old cluster)

Same exercise I have to do for cluster running Cassandra ver 3

Comment: WHOA!! C* version `1.0.12` is way TOO OLD! Please consider upgrading to the latest `4.1`. FYI `5.0` is due to be released in a couple months FWIW!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Dual Write pattern used for data migration. You can setup your application to write the updates to both the new and the old cluster at the same time. And you can keep on migrating data at the same time. This way it  will not matter how long the data transfer takes, your application will have no down time.

Answer (score 0):

Great to know that you're running that old of a version of Cassandra successfully in your production for that long without any upgrades!

There are tools like [**Zero Downtime Migration (ZDM)**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/migrate/introduction.html) which will take care of both delta-loading + provide utilities for point-in-time data migration, but your cluster needs to be at least at a **minimum version supported by the utility** (See `Supported Releases` section on that page, i.e. as of this writing `2.1.6`) and doesn't use Thrift. Your `3.x` cluster can happily use this technique. You will have to write some dual-write application logic for your other older cluster combined with one time migration.

FWIW, `1.0.12` was released over 10+ years ago (06-Aug-2013).